# htaccess redirect file index.php or login.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have some problem with

`This website contains a loop of redirects`

I built a proprietary MVC in which I used a dynamic mod_rewrite, which is read from the array stored in file router.php

I have a structure of directories and files:

```
.htaccess
wwwroot
--router.php
--index.php
--login.php
--ajax.php
```

My router.php

```
'router' =>   array(
                    array( 
                        '/',  
                        array('controller' => 'Start', 'action' => 'dashboard'), 
                        array('methods' => 'GET,POST', 'name' => '/'  )
                    ), // dashboard
                    array('/login', array('controller' => 'Login', 'action' => 'loginForm'), array('methods' => 'GET,POST', 'name' => 'form-login')),
                    array('/message/lista/', array('controller' => 'message', 'action' => 'messageList'), array('methods' => 'GET', 'name' => 'message_list')),
                    array('/message/add/', array('controller' => 'message', 'action' => 'createMessage'), array('methods' => 'POST,GET', 'name' => 'message_add')),
                    array('/message/lista/:page', array('controller' => 'message', 'action' => 'list'), array('methods' => 'GET', 'name' => 'message_list', 'filters' => array('page' => '(\d+)')))
```

File .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?system.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wwwroot/
RewriteRule (.*)$ wwwroot/ [L]
RewriteRule ^login(/)?$ wwwroot/login.php [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)?$ wwwroot/index.php [NC,L]
```

File index.php

```
...
<!-- you are not logged in -->
if (UserSession::validLogin() != true) {
    $logoutUrl = 'login'; // redirect to a log file url http://wwww.system.domain.com/login
        header('Location: ' . $logoutUrl );
    exit();
} else {
 <!-- read the url and redirect to the class
  eg. http://wwww.system.domain.com/task/add -->
}
...
```

When I open http://system.domain.com I see this message
`This website contains a loop of redirects`

If you call this script block in index.php checking whether the user is logged in, the pages are loading correctly (if I type the address manually) 
?
http://system.domain.com/message/add?
The problem begins when you uncomment this piece of code

In htacces I even tried to enter the index.php file load time if no address / login
File .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?system.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wwwroot/
RewriteRule (.*)$ wwwroot/ [L]
RewriteRule ^login(/)?$ wwwroot/login.php [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule !^login(/)?$ wwwroot/index.php [NC,L]
```

Unfortunately does not work to me :( The problem is that I do not know how to force reload the file index.php or login.php, so that when he uses the "header" to not looping.

Can anyone help me?